# How to replace any number in a column with a /

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to replace all the numbers within a column with a "/", Each row is a different number however!

Dummy data:

```
df <- c("M1A","G2A","V3A","L4A","R5A","V6A","G7A","L8A","C9A","P10A","G11A","L12A","T13A","E14A","E15A")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What output do youn want?

Comment: `gsub("\\d+", "/", df)`

Comment: I want the letters to stay the same, but for there to be a / in the place of the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using `sub()` (replaces first occurrence) or `gsub` (replaces all occurrences) of a pattern. The pattern you are looking for is one or more digits, which you can specify with `\\d+` as mentioned in the comment. `\\d` specifies you want to grab digits, `+` specify you want one or more repetitions of it. Hence

```
sub("\\d+", "/", df)
```

will solve your problem. If you want to replace EACH digit with `/` you would then use

```
gsub("\\d", "/", df)
```